# Direct relation between similar matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Given two matrices $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$ that are known to be similar and invertible, is there a way (formula or algorithm)
to determine $\mathbf{R}$ such that $\mathbf{B = R}\,\mathbf{A}\,\mathbf{R}^{\, - \,\mathbf{1}} $, without 
passing through the Jordan decomposition of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A practical way is to solve the linear matrix equation $\mathbf B\mathbf R - \mathbf R \mathbf A=0$ which is equivalent to the linear equation $(\mathbf I\otimes \mathbf B - \mathbf A^T\otimes\mathbf I)vec(\mathbf R) = 0$. The equation has many solutions and each generic solution satisfy $\det(\mathbf R)\ne 0$.

Comment: why is $\det R \ne 0$? Trivially, $R=0$ is a solution...

Comment: Very good answer [+1]...($\mathbf I\otimes \mathbf B - \mathbf A^T\otimes\mathbf I)vec(\mathbf R) = 0$ (where $\otimes$ is Kronecker's product) is equivalent to a homogeneous system of $n^2$ linear equations with $n^2$ linear unknowns (the entries of $R$). See(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

Comment: @user251257 Yes, $\mathbf R=0$ is a solution, there are many other solutions (e.g., if $\mathbf R$ is a solution and  $\mathbf A\mathbf K=\mathbf K\mathbf A$, then $\mathbf R\mathbf K$ is also a solution). If we take a generic $\mathbf R$, then $\det(\mathbf R)\ne 0$.

Comment: what do you mean by a generic $R$? Can you say $R$ is invertible if I give you $R$ as linear combinations of other matrices? Do you mean any non zero solution $R\ne 0$ is invertible? It isn't that I doubt you. I just don't understand that part of your answer.

Comment: @user251257 You have $\mathbf{B = R}\,\mathbf{A}\,\mathbf{R}^{\, - \,\mathbf{1}} \ \Rightarrow \ ( \mathbf I\otimes \mathbf B - \mathbf A^T\otimes\mathbf I)vec(\mathbf R) = 0$ but it is not an equivalence. Thus it is normal to have solutions of the latter that are not solutions of the former, in particular linked with condition $det(R)\neq 0$.

Comment: @user251257 In this case we should find a linear combination which is invertible, but if we take "generic" (random) coefficients, then the result is the invertible matrix with probability one.

Comment: So what you want to say is, if $(I\otimes B - A^T \otimes I) vec R = 0$ and $\det R\ne 0$, then $R$ is what we seek.

Comment: @user251257 Yes, but there are also other solutions.

Comment: thanks for the nice answer, and thanks to commenters for clarifying some aspects of it. So as far as I understand $vec R$ is the null-vector of $(I\otimes B - A^T \otimes I)$, implying that its determinant is null, is that correct ?

Comment: 1) No, the determinant of $R$ has to be $\neq 0$ in order to be able to speak about $R^{-1}$... 2) The null space of $(I\otimes B - A^T \otimes I)$ has in general more than one dimension.

Comment: @GCab Algorithm: 1) form $X=I\otimes B-A^T\otimes I$; 2) compute the matrix N whose columns form the null space of $X$, 3) set $r=N*f$, where $f$ is a vector with random entries; 4) reshape the vector $r$ into the matrix $R$.

Comment: @JeanMarie yes .. sorry, by "its determinant" I intended to refer to $X=(I\otimes B - A^T \otimes I)$. The interesting point is what is the rank of $X$ (  dimension of the null-space). Is there a limit for it?

Comment: @Ignat, same question above

Comment: @Ignat  Does this very nice method have a 'name'?

Comment: **If** $A$ and $B$ are similar, there are solutions of $BR - RA = 0$ where $\det(R) \ne 0$, and then almost every solution has $\det(R) \ne 0$.  If they are not similar, every solution will have $\det(R) = 0$.

Comment: @GCab If I am not mistaken the dimension of the null space is equal to the dimension of $\{K: AK=KA\}$ (= dimension of $\{K: BK=KB\}$, since $A$ and $B$ are similar). So the dimension depends on the Jordan form of $A$ (there exists a formula in terms of sizes of Jordan blocks).

Comment: @H.H.Rugh I do not know the name, I think that the reduction to a matrix equation without $R^{-1}$ is a very natural step.

Comment: It is! Generically (when $A$ and $B$ have simple eigenvalues only) the kernel of the tensor difference has dim $d$ (dim of original vector space)

Comment: @JeanMarie, concerning your comment in reply to user251257, leaving out $det( R )=0$, is $\mathbf B\mathbf R - \mathbf R \mathbf A=0 \; \Leftrightarrow \; ( \mathbf I\otimes \mathbf B - \mathbf A^T\otimes\mathbf I)vec(\mathbf R) = 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is an equivalence, you have exactly the same solutions.