# Find real $P$ s.t. $B=P^{-1}AP$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

TASK:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=Ax$

Given $A=\begin{bmatrix}
    1     & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 2 & -3 \\
    1      & 3 &2
\end{bmatrix}$

Find real matrix $P$ s.t change of coordinates $x=Py$ transforms the system to
and

$\frac{dy}{dt}=By$

$B=\begin{bmatrix}
    1     & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 2 & -3 \\
    0      & 3 &2
\end{bmatrix}$

Solve explicitly for $y$ hence evaluate solution in terms of $x$

APPROACH:

Firstly $PB=AP$

I tried to solve the 9 simultanouesequations and ended up with matrix where there are 3 free variables of the form:

$P=\begin{bmatrix}
    -10x     & 0 & 0 \\
    3x       & y & -z \\
    x      & z &y
\end{bmatrix}$

Then I put this into $P^{-1}AP$ in software "SYMBOLAB" and the asnwer he gave me was $B$. So it turns out $x,y,z$may are free as long as $det(P)\neq0$ And since $det(P)=-10x(y^2+z^2)$, all I know is that $x\neq 0$ and at least one of the $y,z$ is not 0.

Is this the correct answer?

Comment: That is exactly what I did...

Comment: The problem is that I then have to use P to transform variables and solve differential equation system. Obviously the solution will depend on the choice of a,e,f. And i thought the solution must be unique

Comment: so essentially the choice of P is not important? The whole question I got is 

dx/dt= Ax, and using change of variables  x=Py arrive at dy/dt=By and obtain solution for y and then use it to get solution for x

Comment: Id use fundamental matrix but then P would be a complex matrix. this is a part of the coursework and lecturer stated clearly that P must be real. Unless I used the fundamental matrix wrong

Comment: I did edit the Task. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: you may refer to [this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1910237)

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

\begin{align*}
P & =\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & a & b\\
0 & -b & a
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: I care more about the method than the actual answer.

Comment: $A,B$ both leave $K=span\left\{ e_{2},e_{3}\right\} $ invariant,
and $A\big|_{K}=B\big|_{K}$. It suffices to take 
\begin{align*}
P & =1\oplus S
\end{align*}
where $S\in M_{2}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$, invertible, and commutes with $A\big|_{K}$.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the hint given in my comment to a related post, consider that the similarity relation is not unique, because in fact:
$$
\mathbf{A = R}\;\mathbf{C}\;\mathbf{R}^{\,\mathbf{ - 1}} \quad \quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A}\;\mathbf{A}\;\mathbf{A}^{\,\mathbf{ - 1}} } &  \Leftrightarrow  & {\mathbf{A = }\left( {\mathbf{A}\;\mathbf{R}} \right)\;\mathbf{C}\;\left( {\mathbf{A}\;\mathbf{R}} \right)^{\,\mathbf{ - 1}} }  \\
   {\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{C}\;\mathbf{C}\;\mathbf{C}^{\,\mathbf{ - 1}} } &  \Leftrightarrow  & {\mathbf{A = }\left( {\mathbf{R}\;\mathbf{C}} \right)\;\mathbf{C}\;\left( {\mathbf{R}\;\mathbf{C}} \right)^{\,\mathbf{ - 1}} }  \\
   \begin{gathered}
  \mathbf{A} = \lambda \;\mathbf{A}\;\lambda ^{\, - 1}  \hfill \\
  \mathbf{C} = \mu \;\mathbf{C}\;\mu ^{\, - 1}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  &  \Leftrightarrow  & {\mathbf{A = }\left( {\lambda \;\mathbf{R}\;\mu } \right)\;\mathbf{C}\;\left( {\lambda \;\mathbf{R}\;\mu } \right)^{\,\mathbf{ - 1}} }  \\
 \end{array} } \right.
$$