# Matricial Equation

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I solve this equation for matrix $X$ ?

$$AX = BXC$$

(*the letters are all square matrices, and no-space-between means multiplication*)

Comment: what kind of matrices are they?

Comment: if $B$ is invertible, you are solving $MX = XC$ where $M = B^{-1}A$

Comment: I do not think that you can isolate $X$...

Comment: @Ultradark all squares

Comment: @L.B.: good, so insert this information in your post

Comment: @gt6989b this simplifies, indeed. Can X be solved from there?

Comment: Particular case of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/521306 (using Kronecker product alias tensor product)

Comment: $X$ the zero matrix is one solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $B$ and $X$ are invertible, then
$$
\eqalign{
  & AX = BXC\quad \buildrel {B\,invert.} \over
 \longrightarrow   \cr 
  &  \to \quad B^{\, - 1} AX = MX = XC\quad  \to   \cr 
  &  \to \quad M = XCX^{\, - 1}  \cr} 
$$
which means that **$M$ and $C$ must be [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) for $X$ to exist** .

If that is the case, then refer to the answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1910237).